# Experiencing random short freezes after Fedora 28 upgrade

Tags: mouse, freeze, fedora-28

I just upgraded my laptop (Dell Latitude E6540) to Fedora 28 and now the system freezes randomly every few seconds, which is very annoying.

I have searched around and found it might have something to do with system-monitor extension, but when I disable that, it still happens.

After some experimentation, it seems to happen only when I move the mouse, after it hasn't moved for about 10 seconds. It happens to both a USB mouse as the built-in touchpad. The system is completely unresponsive (a ran a simple Python script to test, and that script stops as well), but only for about 1-2 seconds.

Comment: What is the hardware? How is the mouse attached? It's possible this is due to some of the new power saving features enabled in this release. Can you describe how the system is frozen when it freezes? Completely unresponsive, or just the mouse? Can you still ping the machine from another one on your network while the freeze happens?

Comment: @mattdm see updated question, I have not checked the ping-test, but the freeze is so short I doubt you can see anything.

Comment: Same problem after upgrading to Fedora 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no idea what caused it, but an extra update seems to be have fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you add any detail that might help someone else with a similar problem?  Are you saying that just running the update process fixed it?  Do you recall what was updated?

Comment: @fixer1234 that's a hard one, I saw some updates on glibc and the kernel, perhaps it was a hardware issue. Perhaps a setting.